# Resizable div doesn't stay within containment parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

When resizing the middle div, it will not stay within the `containment` parameter on the right boundary of the grid, and it will not resize to the left.

http://jsfiddle.net/dKuER/8/ (clear example, updated)

**HTML**

```
<div id='grid'>

    <div class='outline first top'>
        <div class='container'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='outline top'>
        <div class='container resizable'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='outline last top'>
        <div class='container'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='outline first bottom'>
        <div class='container'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='outline bottom'>
        <div class='container'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='outline last bottom'>
        <div class='container'></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.resizable').resizable({
        containment: "#grid", // Updated to reflect answer, but wasn't the issue.
        handles: "ne,se,nw,sw"
    });
});​
```

Comment: FWIW, it seems that the maximum width and height that you can resize  the blue box is the same as the width and height of `#grid`.

Comment: Grinn, I observed that as well. I don't understand why it is behaving the way it does.

Comment: Very strange indeed. I've tried fiddling with it (no pun intended) with no success. Looks like a bug for sure, but I can't find any fixes for it - or the report for it on jQuery. You may want to do some searching on http://bugs.jqueryui.com

Comment: This will not work. Your `resizable` div is inside another div that's set to inline block. `containment` is not going to work. Can you re-arrange your layout to make the resizable div a child of the containment area?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UD5nk/ - They're `inline-block` elements, but also child of the containment area. Still doesn't work as I would've predicted. The layout is somewhat flexible, but if I can determine what properties are preventing the resizable div to respect the containment area, then hopefully I can work around it.

Comment: I may remove the `containment` option, and add my own containment logic via the `resize` callback, unless someone has a simpler idea.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
containment: "#grid",
```

not confinement.

Comment: +1 Wow, it has been a long day.. however, even with the spell check, it still resizes past the grid's boundaries. Also, it will not resize to the left.

Comment: try adding overflow: hidden; to #grid css

Comment: Putting aside that doesn't fix the resizing to the left issue, the outcome of this isn't desirable. The resizable div can't be resized from the right by hiding the overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the resize isn't calculating in the margins you have set for the outline class. If you remove those, the resize does remain contained to the #grid element. I'm not sure how you want everything else handled, but I would recommend absolute positioning the resizable elements and relative position the $grid container.