# Constraining the position on a resizable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-resizable

This effort is in response to my previously un-answered question: [Resizable div doesn't stay within containment parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854700/resizable-div-doesnt-stay-within-containment-parameter)

Since my `resizable` div, which is referred to as a **pocket**, is not the direct child of the container that I want it contained in, I supplied a callback in the `resize` method that *should* contain it within the container.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dKuER/12/

**My Problem**

When you re-size the `resizable` div to the left (which affects its `left` position) *past* the grid boundary, it does not *always* respect my logic in the callback function. As you drag to the left, you'll notice a blinking action, where the div will switch between its hard-coded `left` position to the `left` position determined by the mouse.

Depending on when you discontinue dragging, the `left` position of the div may either be at the hard-coded position or wherever the mouse stopped dragging.

**How do I make sure the callback function's logic is ALWAYS respected?**

```
// Relevant Code

// No blinking action when dealing with the width 
//Re-sizing to the right works
if ( (pocketLeft + currentWidth) > (gridLeft + gridWidth) ) {
    var deltaWidth = (gridLeft + gridWidth) - (pocketLeft + originalWidth);
    ui.size.width = originalWidth -deltaWidth;
}   

// This should force the position if the div is re-sized 
// past the grid's left boundary
if (pocketLeft < gridLeft) {
    ui.position.left = -120;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am in a hurry right now but if you just want the size of `resizable` div under your `#grid`, you can use `max-height`/`max-width` as I do here: http://jsfiddle.net/dKuER/14/

Comment: @Asif, thanks for the reply. Any of the red boxes could end up being a `resizable` element, so I cannot apply maximums on the div.

Answer (score 0):

Using the mouse coordinates, and the width attained through the `resizable` div's object methods ( so obvious! ), rather than deriving it from some obscure calculations, I was able to achieve the correct effect

http://jsfiddle.net/dKuER/16/

```
var x = event.pageX - $('#grid').offset().left;
var y = event.pageY - $('#grid').offset().top; 

if (x < 0)
{
    ui.size.width = $(this).width();
    ui.position.left = $(this).position().left;
}
```

I achieved this solution trying to understand the core of the jquery.ui.resizable code. However, I maintain there is more acceptable answer than mine.